# R - Error in lqmm(fixed = as.formula(newF), [...] `data' must be a data frame

Tags: r, error-handling

I have data frame df

> str(df) 
>   says explicitly it is a data frame

```
data.frame':    9151 obs. of  16 variables:
```

$ suj    : Factor w/ 20 levels "2","3","4","7",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gender : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DIVA   : Factor w/ 2 levels "non","oui": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A.9    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ H.9    : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ scDIVA : num  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ session: Factor w/ 4 levels "

ran this line

> lqb1 <- lqmm(fixed = simTok  ~ DIVA, random = ~ 1, group = suj, tau = .25, nK = 7, type = "normal", data = df,  control = list(LP_tol_ll = 1e-10,LP_max_iter = 500,verbose=F))

without any specific error message. but when trying to run summary(lqb1), I get this message :

> ...
>   Error in lqmm(fixed = as.formula(newF), random = ~1, group = suj, tau = 0.25,  : 
>     `data' must be a data frame

other command such

> VarCorr(lqb1)  or coef(lqb1)

do not send any error message either.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you worked through `lqmm` vignettes to see exactly how to specify the data? is `simTok` definitely a continuous variable in your d.f.? If you post a reproducible example I'm sure someone will help you out here.

Comment: yes I did ! but apparently there is a conflict with other variables that I am not using for this regression. It is working when I am removing it !